# Why is HOC with styles throwing an error?

Tags: reactjs

I build a HOC and wanted to wrap it withStyles. But then I get the following error. What is wrong?

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

react js

```
const withLoader = (loadingProp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class LoadIndicator extends Component {

    render() {

      return <h1>hello world</h1>
    }
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(withLoader)
```

Comment: Have you imported `Component` from react ?

Comment: Your HOC resolves to another function, it should resolve to a Component, also it should be `({ loading })` not `(loadingProp)`

Comment: @Dominic How would it be correct?  I cannot follow your thoughts

Comment: How are you intending to pass `loadingProp` and `WrappedComponent` to this HOC?

Comment: @Dominic I have the code from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-gentle-introduction-to-hoc-in-react-learn-by-example--cms-30185)

Answer (score 1):

Functional components `return` should always be like `render function` return value is in `class components`.

Following modification to your code should fix your error.

```
class LoadIndicator extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>hello world</h1>
  }
}

const withLoader = (loadingProp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return <LoadIndicator />
}

export default withStyles(styles)(withLoader(loadingProp))
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: you sure. you are running the updated code.? can you please a `small sandbox` demo for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the returned component instead of the HOC function:

```js
const withLoader = (loadingProp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return withStyles(styles)(class LoadIndicator extends Component {

    render() {

      return <h1>hello world</h1>
    }
  }}
}

export default (withLoader)
```

Comment: by pasting this answer I get: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Misplaced the parenthesis, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This loader HOC needs to be instantiated with the prop name of the loading flag.

I'm going to assume the styles HOC is for `LoadIndicator`:

```
const withLoader = (loadingProp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  class LoadIndicator extends Component {

    render() {
      // Todo: render WrappedComponent and/or a loading element.
      return <h1>hello world</h1>
    }
  }

  return withStyles(styles)(LoadIndicator);
}

export default withLoader;
```

Now when you use this HOC you still need to specify what the loading property is called:

```
withLoader('loading')(SomeComponent)
```